# Integration by parts in unbounded subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, how to approach boundary term?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940495/integration-by-parts-on-all-of-mathbbrn-with-n1) it talks about integration by parts in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is said that integration by parts on $\mathbb R^n$ means  integrate by parts on $B(0,R)$ and then let $R\to\infty$. So it would be like this

$$\int_{B(0,R)} u_{x_i} v dx = -\int_{B(0,R)} v_{x_i}u dx + \int_{\partial B(0,R)}uv\nu^idS \  \  \ (i= 1,... , n).$$
Hence, we need to study the limit of the boundary term, which is given by the surface integral over the $n$-dimensional sphere of radius $R$:
$$\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\partial B(0,R)} uv\nu^idS \tag{1}$$

My question is, if instead of $\mathbb R^n$, we had an unbounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$, which is bounded in some direction, how do we study this boundary term in $(1)$?

For example, imagine that instead of $\mathbb R^n$, we have the set $X = \{(x_1, \cdots , x_n) : x_i \geq 0 \mbox{ for } i=1,\cdots,n \}$, by chance, I can consider the boundary surface integral over [Hyperrectangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperrectangle) with a vertex fixed at the origin and make the hyperrectangles grow to infinity, maybe sending all the diagonals to infinity? I appreciate any contribution.

**Question motivation:** I am interested in discovering the behavior of the limit in $(1)$, in unbounded domains, which are not necessarily $\mathbb R^n$, depending on how I can study the boundary term, I would like to understand what to require about the functions $u$ and $v$, so that the limit $(1)$, converge to zero. For example, on $\mathbb R^n$, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940495/integration-by-parts-on-all-of-mathbbrn-with-n1) says that since the area of $\partial B(0,R)$ is proportional to $R^{n-1}$, it suffices to have
$$
|u(x)| |v(x)| = o(R^{1-n})
$$

I'm wondering what happens if we are in a domain that is not all $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: You could take as bounded set $X\cap B(0,R)$ and let $R$ tend to $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you know of a book or material where I can learn more about this?

Comment: Integrals over (hyper)surfaces are the prerequisite of the theorems of *Gauss* and *Stokes* . There are too many books about them that I would recommend a specific one.